# How to express gratitude to an interviewer regardless of the interview outcome?

Tags: politeness, email, phrasing

I'm drafting a thank-you note to the recruiter after a series of onsite interviews with the team. And wondered if it might seem less polite or render a discounted feeling if I included the following phrase.

> As you and the team determine the potential next steps, and regardless of the outcome, it's been a privilege to be considered for the opportunity.

I do want to emphasize that I'm looking forward to hearing from the team on the next steps while also being grateful for the process that I just went through with the team. But don't want my curiosity to learn the final outcome oversize the core idea (gratitude) of my email. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hello, Rc. ELU is not intended to offer style / cordiality advice, but concentrates on individual word meaning and grammar.  I'd try asking this on Interpersonal Skills.SE.

Comment: The best place to ask this is:[Workplace Stack Exchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/?__=1413938178)

Answer (score 0):

A comment can be made on the coherence of the ideas.

"And regardless of the outcome" is a comment on "it's been a privilege to be considered for the opportunity", and as such it is in my opinion somewhat nonsensical. The evaluation that being considered was a privilege even with a possible perspective of not being recruited implies that one considers that in some cases of such situations, without being recruited the opportunity would not be a privilege; this is an implicit thought which someone might not really have, as one is not necessarily in perfect control of what one says, but nevertheless, which insinuates itself in the interlocutor's understanding through the mind of the utterance. It happens that you can conclude in no occasion that being considered could become  a privilege (ie something that you are proud and lucky to have to have the opportunity to do) once you know you have been recruited, that is, you can't do that in any of those particular situations where the opportunity is being considered banal; that is nonsense. However, this is what is implied: given that the eventuality of being recruited is realized, an opportunity considered to be banal could become a privilege.